# Why //= (defined-or) does not work in same way for array as for scalar?

Tags: perl, operators

I have the following code:

```
$var //= 1;
@arr //= qw/ 1 2 3 /;
```

But I get error:

> `Can't modify array dereference in defined or assignment (//=) at ...`

Even this `@arr ||= qw/ 1 2 3 /;` does not work:

> `Can't modify array dereference in logical or assignment (||=) at ...`

But this works as expected:

```
@arr = @arr || qw/ 1 2 3 /;

print "@arr"; # 1 2 3
```

Comment: Array and hash variables can never be undefined, only empty, but that has nothing to do with the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array and hash variables can never be *undefined*, only *empty*. If I write `@arr = undef` then `@arr` becomes a one-element array containing a single undefined scalar. That isn't an undefined array

This expression

```
@arr //= qw/ 1 2 3 /
```

imposes *scalar context* on both operands. `scalar(qw/ 1 2 3 /)` is 3, while `scalar @arr` is the number of elements in `@arr` which cannot be assigned to and can never be undefined anyway

To set an *empty array* use this

```
@arr = qw/ 1 2 3 / unless @arr
```

You could also use a conditional expression

```
@arr = @arr ? @arr : qw/ 1 2 3 /
```

Answer (score 1):

See ["Assignment Operators" in `perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators):

> These combined assignment operators can only operate on scalars...

Comment: See [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) also: `@a = @b || @c;` really means `@a = scalar(@b) || @c;`.

Comment: @Dada: It will be really handy if operands were tested in scalar context, but return them `as is`

Comment: Given that you are answering your own question, you might want to put some effort into explaining the **why** part in more detail than provided in that quotation in `perlop`.

Comment: This question does not answer the question, which was ***Why defined-or does not work in same way for array as for scalar?***. It merely confirms that it is so.